# How to allow file upload without login in Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms, upload

I would like to create a Google form for submission of abstracts. Participants should have the option to add images, Excel files, or PDF. However, as soon as I add the `File upload` field in Forms, one has to log in to participate in the survey.

1. Is there a way to allow file upload without logging in (in the worst case using third-party platforms)?
2. If not, what would be a good alternative to Google Forms that allows this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Google Forms does not allow anonymous uploads. All uploaders need to be logged in with Google accounts. The workaround would be to use some external 3rd-party cloud/server as a gathering point for uploaded files.

Comment: Thanks! Could you suggest examples how / where that could be done?

Comment: an example would be https://www.sharefile.com/

Comment: the user can upload the file on services like - https://pasteboard.co/ and submit the generated link.

Answer (score 2):

This website offers a feasible solution: https://forms.studio

I just tried it and it works very nicely. [This](https://forms.studio/demo) is a demo.
Their [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/unaDRVKy_uA) walks you through the necessary steps.
In a nutshell one needs to copy [their Google sheets file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1asW7o1IbsdqrZllJH-yzohaS9BVyPVbocpNSIPK26-M/copy) including the necessary scripts and then activate and edit it.

*Using scripts from unknown parties can be potentially dangerous. Proceed at your own risk.*

Comment: Note that this product is paid and trial expires in 4 days.